# Android - format Date to "Day, Month dd, yyyy"

Tags: java, android, date-format

I get from the user, the date he sets in a DatePickerDialog. The date i get is in this format:

```
int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay
```

Can i format it to be like this  "Day, Month dd, yyyy" as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Thank you all for you aswers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the values returned from picker

```
    int selectedYear = 2013;
    int selectedDay = 20;
    int selectedMonth = 11;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDay);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
    String format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d, yyyy").format(cal.getTime());
```

Answer (score 6):

You can Try This:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE-dd-MM-yyyy"); // Set your date format
String currentData = sdf.format(your actual date); // Get Date String according to date format
```

Here you can see details and all supported format:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the date:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDay);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    String DATE_FORMAT = "EE, MMM dd, yyyy";
    sdf.applyPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: `String DATE_FORMAT =  "EE, MM dd, yyyy";`
is not used.